# Building an app on Facebook using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to build a simple "app" on Facebook that will display alternate content depending if a user "likes" my page.

1. Why the following JS doesn't work (doesn't send the response back. No
   response = no like, array = response)? When I process the query on
   FB query tester it works.
2. Why does it generate the following error?

   ```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
   <script>
     FB.init({
       appId  : 'APP_ID',
       status : true, // check login status
       cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
       channelUrl : 'http://domain.com/tab/', // channel.html file
       oauth  : false // enable OAuth 2.0
     });

    (function($) {

     var session = FB.getSession();
         FB.api({
              method: 'fql.query',
              query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=APP_ID'
         },
      function(response) {
         if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0)
             alert("YOU LIKE US!");
         else
             alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
      });
    })(jQuery);
   </script>
   ```

Error

```
Object { error_code="104", error_msg="Requires valid signature", request_args=[7]}
```

Comment: Facebook will send this info to your page in the `signed_request`, which means that you need a server-side language to read it. Unfortunately, the JS-SDK will not give you such information UNLESS the user is connected to your app which is not what you need I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** You should not need `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` unless you are running an application with Facebook connect (an application that will not run on Facebook. Many mobile applications are a great example of this. Look at [this SO question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175047/facebook-app-vs-facebook-connect-site). Any application that will run through a tab or on a Facebook page does not use Facebook connect.

You may want to try using the init method that I showed you instead of what you are using. It would look like this:

**Your HTML Page**

```
<body>
<!-- Code -->
<!-- FB Required -->    
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">iframeReady();</script>
</body>
```

**Your JS file**

```
function iframeReady(){
    //Facebook iFrame include
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'YOURAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        loginUser();
    };

    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
}
```

One more thing you may need (which I should have noticed a little earlier) depending on your page settings is an extended permission to get the user likes.

```
/*
 * Logs in a user.
 */
function loginUser() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
            if (response.perms) {
                //User has logged in and accepted permissions
            } else {
                //User did not accept permissions 
            }
        } else {
            //User did not login
        }
    }, { perms: "user_likes" });
}
```

You could also look into [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

You are using FB.getSession, which [should not be used on page load](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getSession/). From that link:

> NOTE: You should never use this method at page load time. Generally,
>   it is safer to use FB.getLoginStatus() if you are unsure.

Once you have permissions you should be able to make that query call (assuming it is correct).

If that doesn't fix anything, then make sure that all you app settings are correct (EXACT URL, App Id, ect.)

If that is all correct then the issue is with your query. Let me know and I will see if I can find the issue

Comment: Ahh, Ok. Is this an application that will run inside a facebook tab, or is there more then one instance this line: `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` If the app is run inside of facebook then remove that line, and make sure that there are no other occurrences of that line if not (If you generate a facebook 'Like' button, then they usually have that line appended to the beginning

Comment: Removing that line caused FB to be undefined. I am using an iframe. I looked through the articles but all of them are server side based.

Comment: Hmm... You shouldn't need the connect statement if you are making a facebook application that will run inside of facebook (through an iFrame). Im going to rewrite my answer. See if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to include your `access_token` with every request of `fql`, it wasn't a mandate before but now it is.

This is what Facebook says:

```
GET /fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()&access_token=...
```

Answer (score 1):

add access_token to your api request.

```
  FB.api({
       method: 'fql.query',
       access_token : [YOUR TOKEN],
       query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND page_id=APP_ID'
  },
```